# Writing $M=\sum_{i=1}^{N}ia_i$ in terms of $S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following sums:

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i$$

and
$$M=\sum_{i=1}^{N}ia_i$$

since $M$ is a specific linear combination of elements of $S$ but with natural numbers in order, can one write $M$ in terms of $S$?

Comment: $S$ is invariant under permutations of the summands $a_i$, but $M$ is not, so there is likely no equality relation in general

Comment: If you allow $N$ to vary, then writing $S:=S_N$, one has $M=NS_N-(S_1+\cdots+S_{N-1})$.

Comment: Yes: $M = \lambda S$ for $\lambda = {M\over S}$, demonstrating that you need to define what you mean by "in terms of"

Answer (score 3):

Assume such a function exsits, namely, $M=f(S)$, then we have:

$$f(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_N)=a_1+2a_2+\dots+Na_N$$

If $a_k=c, \forall k\in\{1,\dots,N\}$, we have

$$S=Nc, M=\frac{(1+N)Nc}{2}\Rightarrow M=f(S)=\frac{(1+N)}{2}S$$

Suppose there exists $a_p\neq a_q, ~~1\le p<q\le N$, then we have

$$pa_p+qa_q\neq pa_q+qa_p$$

hence,
$$\begin{align}f(a_1+\dots+a_q\dots+a_p+\dots+a_N)&=a_1+\dots+pa_q\dots+qa_p+\dots+Na_N\\
\\
&\neq a_1+\dots+pa_p\dots+qa_q+\dots+Na_N\\
\\
&=f(a_1+\dots+a_p\dots+a_q+\dots+a_N)\\
\\
\Rightarrow f(S)&\neq f(S)\end{align}$$

We get contradictions.